# Updating Profile Attributes using Web Collect?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a use case where I want to achieve an update of user's profile attributes, from pages outside the marketing cloud, meaning that AMPscript is not available to me.

Question is - can i do this via the setUserInfo and collect tracking script?

Alternatively, can i use collect to add somebody to a instead? (for my particular use case, I believe I could manage with some export of those on the list, and then taking it from there).

Comment: I believe your idea of using the Collect Tracking Script and the setUserInfo (and customer attributes as needed) could work but you may need to engage SF for customer services in order to make those values actually populate in a data extension.  Alternatively, you could use the "Web Collect" mechanism, which is actually different than the "Collect Tracking Code" - more details here:
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the Contact Key, you can use the [**Update Contact**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateContacts.htm) via the REST API.

If you don't know the Contact key, you can perform a [**Search Contact**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/searchSchema.htm) to find the Contact Key using collected attributes/values.

Comment: Hey cameron - thanks for this. I'm aware of the API capabilities, but do you know the extent to which we can leverage the collect script? Either to update a field or to add them to a list?